# SQL - Retrieve Records from Day Before Yesterday

Tags: mysql, sql

I"m trying to retrieve records from the day before yesterday. The query below returns the records from yesterday...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `DATE` > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND `DATE` < CURDATE()
```

The following query returns the records from the day before AND yesterday...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `DATE` > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY) AND `DATE` < CURDATE()
```

Though I'd really like to obtain records for ONLY the day before yesterday. I'm trying the following query, but it's not working...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `DATE` > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY) AND `DATE` < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would try `DATE_SUB` instead of `DATE_ADD` since you are subtracting. I'm not sure if this is the problem though. You can also try `SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)` to see what date is being returned.

Comment: the problem might be your system date. check `select curdate()`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a simpler method, without DATE_ADD or DATE_SUB :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

to retrive records from yesterday :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

But if your `DATE` column is a DATETIME :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE = CURDATE() - 2;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table where DATE = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work, or a combination of >= and <

Basically, you're looking for a date range that can't exist.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `DATE` = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
```